# Python And EJABBER/XMPP

Tags: python, xmpp

I have to write a program in `python` that can `shutdown/hibernate/restart` the windows/Linux base operating systems through the `EJABBER/XMPP` server , Now i wondering that what is EJABBER and how should i start this project ?
does anyone have any idea about this ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you mean JABBER/XMPP, not EJABBER...

Answer (score 2):

You could write a Jabber bot that connects to a Jabber server and waits for commands that are sent to it, for example by using the [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) networking library together with a library for Jabber support, e.g. [Wokkel](http://wokkel.ik.nu/).

Some projects for writing jabber bots in python already exist, too. You might for example base your project on [python-jabberbot](http://thp.io/2007/python-jabberbot/)